# Visual Studio, Add - New item (Class) window not selecting Class1.cs automaticlly

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a problem when I add a new item (class) to project, it doesn't automaticlly select the Class1.cs text.. I have to manually select it and write a new class name.. kinda annoying and dunno what have happened. I have re-installed VS2022, even 2019 and checked all settings.. But can't figure it out..

I wonder if someone knows how to fix this issue..

[Add new item (class)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrpdd.png)

[As you can see on this image, it is not automaticlly selecting the Class1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L84EX.png)

As you can see on my last image, it's not selecting Class1.cs which is pretty annoying when I want to make new class.

Comment: Add New Item focuses on you selecting the item you want first.  Consider Project > Add Class

Comment: Ah, I see. But the weird thing is that the way I explained above works for some of my friends  and colleagues, even if they Add new item, it always select the text field either way